# Why socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0) returns -1?

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, visual-c++

I trying to create a socket application on visual studio c++, but I can't.

The problem is `int listen_sock = socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0)` returns -1 and I don't know why...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should print the error (using [`GetLastError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679360.aspx)). I suspect you are not initializing things:

```
WSADATA wsaData = {0};
WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
```

Comment: You need to use `WSAGetLastError()`, not `GetLastError()`.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau - TeamB According to [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681391.aspx), `GetLastError` also returns errors related to WSA.

Comment: That is an implementation detail. Both `GetLastError()` and `WSAGetLastError()` happen use the same thread-local storage right now, but that could always change in the future. All of the WinSock functions are documented to use `WSAGetLastError()`, not `GetLastError()`. Use what the documentation says to use, not what happens to work today.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau - TeamB Thanks, awesome info :-)

Answer (score 4):

What does `WSAGetLastError` return?  Did you call `WSAStartup` before doing this call?